# Style tags not recognized in Word document

Tags: html, ms-word, doc

I have some content with Html tags (like "p", "span", etc).

```
Ex. 
<p><span class="clsStyle1">Some content</span>
<br/>
<span>Further content</span></p>
...
```

Some of the "span" elements have classes assigned to them, which are used for styles.

```
Ex. <span class="clsStyle1">Some content</span>
```

I have included the definition for "clsStyle1" in a "" tag and the final HTML code looks something similar to this:

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
.clsStyle1 {
    border-color: #38FD11;
}
</style>

<p><span class="clsStyle1">Some content</span>
<br/>
<span>Further content</span></p>
...

</body>
<html>
```

Finally, I am saving this content with a ".doc" extension.

When opening this content in Microsoft Word, it displays the content, but does not recognize the styles.

Is there any way to transform the available styles to a format that Word can understand, before exporting the Html content to Word?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word recognizes the styles, but in your example case, the style has no effect. Setting `border-color` has no impact on rendering when the border style is `none`, which is the default value. If you add e.g.

```
border-style: solid;
```

you will see a border of the desired color.